# How to call Session variables in another project in the Same Solution Asp .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-3.0

I am running multiple projects in my system, as shown below:

1. Startup project is Project 1
2. BLL Project (in this project I am setting the session)
3. Common Project (in this project only I want to call the session)

In this class, I cannot create a constructor. This is my class:

```
namespace Project.Common
{
   public class Share
   {
        public const string SESSION_CURRENT_COMPANY = "Company";

        public static int LoggedInMembersCompanyID
        {
            get
            {    
                    var companyIdSession = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(Common.SESSION_CURRENT_COMPANY);
                    int _companyIdSessionID = 0;
                    if (companyIdSession != null)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(companyIdSession.ToString(), out _companyIdSessionID);
                    }
                    return _companyIdSessionID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: What's your question?  Do you want to share the string constant "Share.SESSION_CURRENT_COMPANY" between classes?  Or do you want to share the class (and the constant) between separate MSVS projects?  Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to add this in the startup.cs Configure Function just before app.UsesEndpoits

   `Common.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>(), Configuration);`
2. Go to the  Common Project and Go to Common.cs add the following thing at the top:

```
private static IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor; 
private static IConfiguration _configuration;
public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,IConfiguration configuration)
{
                _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
                _configuration = configuration;
}
```

3. Get the Session value as shown below :

```
public static int LoggedInMembersCompanyID
{
  get
     { 
       var companyIdSession = HttpContext.Current.Session[Share.SESSION_CURRENT_COMPANY];
       int _companyIdSessionID = 0;
       if (companyIdSession != null)
       {
         int.TryParse(companyIdSession.ToString(), out _companyIdSessionID);
       }
        return _companyIdSessionID; 
    }
}
```